# Push element to an immutable List without reassigning variable

Tags: javascript, immutable.js, immutablelist

How to avoid reassign of variables while iterating over an immutable List, to create another one. I have the code below, which is working fine,

```
function foobar(stateValue) {
let propsValue = List();
stateValue.forEach((categoryItem) => {
    categoryItem.get('coveragePayorIds', List()).forEach((
        coveragePayorId) => {
        const category = categoryItem.get('category');
        propsValue = propsValue.push({
        category,
        coverage_payor_id: coveragePayorId,
        });
    });
});
return propsValue;
}
```

I'm trying to make the `propsValue` a const. How it can be achieved?

Comment: Don't use `foreach`. Use a reduction (`reduce`) instead. If you're going to use immutable structures, use functional looping methods.

Comment: What exactly is `stateValue`, is it an array or a List?

Comment: @Bergi The stateValue will be similar to as ' [Map({ coveragePayorIds: [{coveragePayorIds: Map({category: 33}), b: 'foo'}], category: 2, c: 3 })]'

Comment: OK. With a list, you could have used `flatMap` :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forEach` is all about side effects and doesn't work with immutable structures or variables. Don't use it.

```
function foobar(stateValue) {
    return List(stateValue).flatMap(categoryItem => {
        const category = categoryItem.get('category');
        return categoryItem.get('coveragePayorIds', List()).map(coverage_payor_id =>
            ({category, coverage_payor_id})
        );
    });
}
```